# Forking a new process when Node.JS receives a connection

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm running a Node.JS application involving heavy child process I/O.  Due to the way Node.JS handles file descriptors (among other reasons), I want to fork a new V8 instance for every connection to the server.  (Yes, I'm aware that this is a potentially expensive operation, but that's not the point of this question.)

I am using [nssocket](https://github.com/nodejitsu/nssocket) for my server, but this question should apply to other types of Node.JS servers (express, Socket.IO, etc) as well.

Right now I have:

```
var server = require("nssocket").createServer(function(socket){
    // Do stuff with the new connection
}).listen(8000);
```

The intuitive thing to do is this:

```
// master.js
var server = require("nssocket").createServer(function(socket){
    // Fork a new process to handle the connection
    child_process.fork("worker.js");
}).listen(8000);

// worker.js
// Do stuff with the new connection
```

However, then the child process won't have access to the `socket` variable.

I've read about the new [cluster API](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) in Node, but it doesn't look like it's designed for the case when you want *every* connection to spawn a new worker.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster API is probably closest to what you want. In theory you can call `cluster.fork()` at any time within the master process. Note that once the socket connection is established, there is afaik no way to hand it over to another process.

To forward the communication to the worker, you could use message passing (i.e. `worker.send`) or you could open another port in the worker process and direct the client there.

I should stress that running significantly more worker processes than CPU cores is probably not a good idea. Have you considered pooling the workers or using a work queue like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)?

Comment: client & server sockets can be sent through messages, see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_server_object: `forked.send('socket', socket);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cluster module to fork workers, then IPC (Inter-process communication) channel plus a messaging queue to pass objects between master process and workers. A good option would be [ZMQ](https://www.npmjs.org/package/zmq).